# 400 Bad Request - Ajax with Jquery and Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Iḿ trying to use ajax in my JQuery script to read a JQuery var into functions.php of Wordpress.

```
$.ajax({

    url: js_admin_url.ajax_url,
                  type: 'POST',
                  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "CloudSight [key]");
                  },
                  data: JSON.stringify({
                      'action': 'send_ranking_data', // Ação do Ajax
                      '_ajax_nonce': js_admin_url.nonce,
                      's': settings.ranking // O que vamos postar para $_POST
                  }),
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  success: function(response) { console.log(response); },
                  error: function(e) { console.log(e); }
              });
```

Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

I see at least that you shouldn't be using `JSON.stringify` with your ajax data, just do:

```
data: {
    'action': 'send_ranking_data',
    '_ajax_nonce': js_admin_url.nonce,
    's': settings.ranking
}
```

And that will automatically send the data as JSON